# Magento: getting attributes from an attribute set without a product

Tags: attributes, magento, drop-down-menu, set

I have set an attribute set in my Magento shop which has several binary attributes.

For a pulldown I need a list of ALL the attributes inside this one attribute set, including their internal name and their label. Since this pulldown should appear in places that not necessarily have a product selected I can't go the usual route of "getting the attributes of a product".

How do I go about of getting a list of all the attributes inside my set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I realised that I missed that you want the whole set of attributes, not just an individual one.  Try this:

```
$productEntityType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY);

$attributeSetCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection');
$attributesInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
    ->setEntityTypeFilter($productEntityType->getId())  //4 = product entities
    ->addSetInfo()
    ->getData();
```

You'll then need to iterate through the array that is returned with something like:

```
foreach($attributesInfo as $attribute):
    $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->load($attribute['attribute_id']);
    echo 'label = '.$attribute->getFrontendLabel().'<br/>';
    echo 'code = '.$attribute->getAttributeCode().'<br/><br/>';
endforeach;
```

Sorry for missing the original point, hope this helps!

Cheers,
JD

Comment: Much better. When I use your code I get a list of attributes, but not my custom ones. I got those by switching "->setEntityTypeFilter" from 4 to 10, even though I'm not sure why 10. I just got there by randomly trying. :)

Thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem.  You should be able to find the id of your entity by looking in the eav_entity_type table in the db.  Looks like 10 = sales/quote_payment, at least in Mage v1.4.1

Pleased that it worked for you :)
JD

Answer (score 5):

In order to get all the attributes in an attribute set, you can use as:

```
$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')
                ->setType('catalog_product')
                ->getTypeId();
$attributeSetName   = 'Default'; //Edit with your required Attribute Set Name
$attributeSetId     = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId)
                    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name', $attributeSetName)
                    ->getFirstItem()
                    ->getAttributeSetId();
$attributes = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($attributeSetId);
foreach($attributes as $_attribute){
    print_r($_attribute);
}
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

try this snippet, it should give you want you need, except for multi-select attributes.

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product','attribute_name');
    foreach($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true,true) as $option){
        $attributeArray[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
    }
    return $attributeArray;
```

Hope this helps,
JD

Comment: Nope, just returns me an empty array. :(